# Getting some {({})()(} out of my JSX

Tags: reactjs

So I am learning react and am struggling a bit to really get a clear understanding of what exactly all the { ( } ) are doing, where, why and how in JSX.

So I ended up producing this snippet of code here:

```
            <Connect query={ graphqlOperation(ListEvents) }>
                { ( { data: { listEvents } } ) =>
                    <div> {
                    listEvents ? (
                        <ListView events={listEvents.items}/>
                        ) : (
                        <h3> Loading </h3>
                    )} </div>
                }
            </Connect>
```

What I am hoping something could do for me is, what is a different way to rewrite that? Hopefully cleaner? More concise? Fewer (){}?

I've tried rewriting a few different ways but ended up breaking it.

Is there a way?

Comment: Are you able to link Component code?

Answer (score 1):

so, here you are passing some object say `x` in which it contains a object called 'data'.In `data` object you have key called `listEvents`.

You are getting the key `listEvents` using spread operator introduced in ES6,its not JSX.

Further,you are checking if the key called `listEvents` has value.If the value is present then `pass the value` or else display `spinner` using ternary operator within JSX.

If you could share where you want acheive the same,i can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you [decompile](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQHgwg9gdlCmDGAXYBHArrATgTwLwG9gBzTAQwAcALFAGwHlytTEBLaACgBkWBnRAUQBusKIh4BKYAF8AfAChgipcpXBC7NcAAmzUgC5NNXgOGie0i5NzzVt2yC0tBMtQrvvFRvkJFjgAfmB2Nw9Q0G4-ADUWWAB3YFhTMQIvE18eADoWRFgAWx4pAHobMNDJA2DS0JBKAGYXTghSRygiUEK6kqrlcSl2x2cQ0qkhuxBCyBgERBkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) the code in Javascript it would look like this

```
React.createElement(
    Connect,
    { query: graphqlOperation(ListEvents) },
    function (_ref) {
        var listEvents = _ref.data.listEvents;
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            " ",
            listEvents ? React.createElement(ListView, { events: listEvents.items }) : React.createElement(
                "h3",
                null,
                " Loading "
            ),
            " "
        );
    }
);
```

**details**

when you query `graphqlOperation(ListEvents)` it would result with a callback `function (_ref)`

then you are getting `listEvents` from the callback result -

```
var listEvents = _ref.data.listEvents;
```

And the rest its checking if `listEvents` has data along with it then use it in a component.

You can try it with online [babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQHgwg9gdlCmDGAXYBHArrATgTwLwG9gBzTAQwAcALFAGwHlytTEBLaACgBkWBnRAUQBusKIh4BKYAF8AfAChgipcpXBC7NcAAmzUgC5NNXgOGie0i5NzzVt2yC0tBMtQrvvFRvkJFjgAfmB2Nw9Q0G4-ADUWWAB3YFhTMQIvE18eADoWRFgAWx4pAHobMNDJA2DS0JBKAGYXTghSRygiUEK6kqrlcSl2x2cQ0qkhuxBCyBgERBkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're overwhelmed by this line:

```
{ ( { data: { listEvents } } ) =>   
    ....  
}
```

So this is basically a JSX expression, that contains an arrow function:

```
{  (object) =>   
    ... we omit the {} cause it's returning a single value (the <div>)
}
```

Once we got that figure out, let's see [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Your argument `object` has property `data`, which in turn as a property `listEvents`. We destructure like this:

```
// The 3 statements below are the same

(object) => { /* do something with `object.data.listEvents` */ }

({ data }) => { /* do something with `data.listEvents` */ }

({ data: { listEvents } }) => { /* do something with `listEvents` */ }
```

So there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the child function into a method and use it as a child node:

```
RenderList = ( { data: { listEvents } } ) => {
  if (listEvents) {
    return <ListView events={listEvents.items}/>
  }

  return <h3>Loading</h3>
}

render() {
  <Connect query={ graphqlOperation(ListEvents) }>
    <this.RenderList />
  </Connect>
}
```